# Dragging in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have placed the ruler inside a particular div and there everything works fine.
But the ruler were allowing me to drag only from overall body of the window, but its showing the ruler line inside the div which I have included.
I want to drag this from the div in which I have placed the ruler. I have dragged from the screen margin 0px to drag the blue line.
But I want to drag from red line which is basically my div. Thanks in advance.

In html:-

```
<div style="width: 100px;height: 400px;" class="demo">
    <div class="main-wrapper" id="test" style="width: 400px;height: 300px;"></div></div>
```

am using RulersGuides js and I want the drag to be worked inside the main-wrapper class.

Comment: Please provide the code you have written, it's a lot easier to help then.

Comment: Thanks @UjwalRatra,  hope the above code will be enough and the js is open-source.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#main-wrapper" ).draggable();
  });
  </script>
Use the below jquery plugins to work properly.
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you so much @shajeerpuzhakkal , but am looking for the ruler drag not the normal jquery drag. This drag basically works like photoshop